# easier and shorter way to sum values in a hash of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

Having a hash of hashes like this:

```
d = {a: {c: 1, d:3 }, b: {c: 2, d: 6}, ...}
```

What is the easier way to sum all values in `c:`?

Comment: "easier" and "shorter" than *what*?

Comment: _"sum all values in c:"_ – what you mean by that? What's your expected result?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "What is the easier way to sum all values in `c:`?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 3):

```
d.values.map { |val| val[:c] }.reduce(&:+)
```

To explain:

```
d.values
=> [{:c=>1, :d=>3}, {:c=>2, :d=>6}]

d.values.map { |val| val[:c] }
=> [1, 2]
```

From this point you can use `reduce(&:+)` to get the sum, or if you're using rails (or have required active support), you can use Array#sum

`reduce(&:+)`, by the way, is a shorthand for `reduce { |memo, val| memo + val }`

Comment: You can omit `&`.

Comment: `Array#sum` is available in Ruby >= 2.4

Answer (score 2):

Just go over the hashes and sum their `:c` values.

```
d.values.sum { |h| h[:c] }
=> 3
```

Even shorter (from Sagar Pandya's comment):

```
d.sum { |_, v| v[:c] }
=> 3
```

Comment: `d.sum { |_,v| v[:c] }`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to permit nested hashes of arbitrary depth you can use the following recursive method.

```
def sum_cees(h)
  h.sum { |k,v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? sum_cees(v) : k == :c ? v : 0 }
end

sum_cees({ a: { c: 1, d:3 }, b: { d: { m: { c: 2, e: 6 } }, f: { c: 3} },
           g: { c: 4 },  n: { r: 3 } })
  #=> 10
```